# How to reinstall shortcut icons when during repair and change mode with WiX installer 3.7

Tags: wix

I am new to the Wix Installer and I have been trying to re-install the shortcut icons on desktop etc in **"Change" and "Repair"** mode but its not working. It only works in Installation mode. Could someone please help me to resolve this issue?

Following is the code been used:

```
<DirectoryRef Id="ApplicationProgramsFolder">
     <Component Id="ApplicationShortcuts" Guid="{964EEA43FA8A}">

        <Shortcut Id="ApplicationStartMenuShortcut" Name="$(var.ShortcutText)" Advertise="yes" Description="$(var.ShortcutComment)" Target="[ProductDir]$(var.ShortcutTarget)" WorkingDirectory="ProductDir" Icon="AA.exe" />

        <?if $(var.AA) != "True" ?>

           <Shortcut Id="ApplicationDesktopShortcut" Directory="DesktopFolder" Name="$(var.ShortcutText)" Target="[ProductDir]$(var.ShortcutTarget)" WorkingDirectory="ProductDir" Icon="AA.exe" Description="$(var.ShortcutComment)" />

        <?endif?>

        <?if $(var.Configuration) = "Debug" ?>

           <Shortcut Id="UninstallProduct" Name="Uninstall $(var.AAName)" Description="Uninstall $(var.YAName)" Target="[SystemFolder]msiexec.exe" Arguments="/x [ProductCode]" />

        <?endif?>

        <RemoveFolder Id="ApplicationProgramsFolder" On="uninstall" />

        <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\Microsoft\MyApplicationName" Name="installed" Type="integer" Value="1" KeyPath="yes" />
     </Component>

     <Component Id="OnUninstall" Guid="{739C22AD-8716F39}">

        <CreateFolder/>

        <RemoveFile Id="RemoveFiles" Directory="ProductDir" Name="*.*" On="uninstall" />

        <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" KeyPath="yes" Id="BogusKey" Name="Foom" Type="string" Key="Torp" Value="Geekle" />

     </Component>

  </DirectoryRef>
```

Comment: You probably need to find out what your REINSTALLMODE is being set to on the repair. If it includes "s" the docs say that shortcuts are reinstalled.  Change won't repair them.

Comment: How about adding a control to change dialog and ask user with a checkbox and publish event='ReinstallMode' with value 's' for it?